# How To Use A CSS Class in an ERB Do Statement | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a do statement in my view and was wondering how to format the code properly to use a class like other elements?

```
<%= link_to something_path do %>
  <div>Stuff</div>
<% end %>
```

I tried to do it like most ERB, adding the class to the end of the statement:

```
<%= link_to something_path do, class: "classname" %>
```

That didn't work so I tried to do it like an `image_tag`:

```
<%= link_to(something_path do, class: "classname") %>
```

Where does `class:` fit into this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<%= link_to(something_path, class: "classname") do %>
  <div>Stuff</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

It also has this example,

```
link_to "Articles", articles_path, id: "news", class: "article"
# => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```